# Xamarin Android Binding to Java Type which inherits Generic Type

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm looking for a workaround for the following problem. Given a class hierarchy in Java:

```
public interface Bar<T> { 
    getValue<T>();
}

public abstract class BarImpl<T> implements Bar<T> {

}

public class Foo extends BarImpl<Double> {
    @override 
    public Double getValue() {
        // .. 
    }
}
```

Xamarin.Android generates wrappers as follows:

```
// Now in C# land
public interface Bar 
{
    // Xamarin.Android omits T Value { get; }
}

public partial abstract class BarImpl : Bar  
{
    // Xamarin.Android omits abstract T Value { get; }
}

public partial class Foo : BarImpl
{
    // COMPILE ERROR HERE. No method to override
    public override java.lang.Double Value 
    {
        get { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

Now I'm well aware that Java compilation strips out generics information, so this isn't actually an easy problem to solve but I do want to know if:

- Anyone has come across similar problems in java.android
- What clever solutions you employed to bind this class hierarchy?

I'm only interested in the getter of Value on Foo (bound c# class) and some way to access it via the base interface (cast is OK).

Comment: aren't the generated classes partial? o0

Comment: Yes, they are, but how do I remove the override on Foo.Value for a start?

Comment: Oh ... you're saying exclude the node Foo.Value altogether and declare it in partial classes? ...

Comment: maybe or just add an extra interface and implement it in your partial class

Comment: ... I'll give it a go. What Xamarin.Android has done with this is a total mess ... : /

Comment: I've scratched in an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generator generates partial classes. Extending these could be a solution. All you have to do, is to add files to the `Additions` folder and ad your stuff to the partial classes. My idea would look like:

```
// custom interface
public interface IMyBar<T> : Bar<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }
}

// extend the partial base class
public partial abstract class BarImpl : IMyBar<Java.Lang.Double>  
{
    public abstract Java.Lang.Double Value { get; }
}

// compiler generates the rest
public partial class Foo
{
    // COMPILE ERROR HERE. No method to override
    public override Java.Lang.Double Value 
    {
        get { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I didn't use exactly this solution (due to a slightly more complex hierarchy than in my question), it did point me to the solution, which was to remove spurious nodes created by Xamarin.Android and write my own hierarchy in Additions (partial classes). Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up going another route and creating my own java wrappers around these generic interfaces so things would bind without issues.
So instead of using the supplied interfaces which inherited from generics, I created my own which did not inherit and passed them into java methods which wrapped the previous ones.